# Why are my slurm job steps not launching in parallel?

Tags: slurm

I am trying to figure out what the concept of "tasks" means in SLURM. I have found [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53759961/3082472) that suggests me the following job script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --ntasks=2

srun --ntasks=1 sleep 10 & 
srun --ntasks=1 sleep 12 &
wait
```

The author says that this job runs for him in 12 seconds in total, because the two steps `sleep 10` and `sleep 12` run in parallel but I cannot reproduce that.

If I save the above file as `slurm-test` and run

```
sbatch -o slurm.out slurm-test,
```

I see that my job runs for 23 seconds.

This is the output of `sacct --format=JobID,Start,End,Elapsed,NCPUS -S now-2minutes`:

```
       JobID               Start                 End    Elapsed      NCPUS
------------ ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
645514       2021-06-30T11:05:38 2021-06-30T11:06:00   00:00:22          2
645514.batch 2021-06-30T11:05:38 2021-06-30T11:06:00   00:00:22          2
645514.exte+ 2021-06-30T11:05:38 2021-06-30T11:06:00   00:00:22          2
645514.0     2021-06-30T11:05:38 2021-06-30T11:05:48   00:00:10          2
645514.1     2021-06-30T11:05:48 2021-06-30T11:06:00   00:00:12          2
```

My `slurm.out` output is

```
srun: Job 645514 step creation temporarily disabled, retrying (Requested nodes are busy)
srun: Step created for job 645514
```

Explicitly incuding `-n 2` in the `sbatch` call does not change the result. What am I doing wrong? How can I get the two calls in my job file to run simultaneously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the Slurm version you might have to add the `--exclusive` parameter to srun (which has different semantics than for `sbatch`):

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --ntasks=2

srun --ntasks=1 --exclusive -c 1 sleep 10 & 
srun --ntasks=1 --exclusive -c 1 sleep 12 &
wait
```

Also adding `-c 1` to be more explicit might help, again depending on the Slurm version.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the reason for `step creation temporarily disabled, retrying (Requested nodes are busy)` is because, the `srun` command that executed first, allocated all the memory. To solve this, one first optionally(?) specify the total memory allocation in `sbatch`:

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
#SBATCH --mem=[XXXX]MB
```

And then specify the memory use per `srun` task:

```
srun --exclusive --ntasks=1 --mem-per-cpu [XXXX/2]MB sleep 10 & 
srun --exclusive --ntasks=1 --mem-per-cpu [XXXX/2]MB sleep 12 &
wait
```

I didn't specify cpu count for `srun` because in my `sbatch` script I have `#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1`. For the same reason I suspect you should use `--mem` instead of `--mem-per-cpu` in the `srun` command when your job isn't serial, but I haven't tested this configuration.