# Running parallel jobs in slurm

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, slurm

I was wondering if I could ask something about running slurm jobs in parallel.(Please note that I am new to slurm and linux and have only started using it 2 days ago...)

As per the insturctions on the picture below (source : https://hpc.nmsu.edu/discovery/slurm/tasks/serial-execution/),

[image: instructions on how to run parallel job]

I have designed the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name fmriGLM #job name을 다르게 하기 위해서
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH -t 16:00:00 # Time for running job
#SBATCH -o /scratch/connectome/dyhan316/fmri_preprocessing/FINAL_loop_over_all/output_fmri_glm.o%j #%j : job id 가 [>
#SBATCH -e /scratch/connectome/dyhan316/fmri_preprocessing/FINAL_loop_over_all/error_fmri_glm.e%j
pwd; hostname; date
#SBATCH --ntasks=30
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=3000MB
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1


for num in {0..29}

do
srun --ntasks=1 python FINAL_ARGPARSE_RUN.py --n_division 30 --start_num ${num} &
done

wait
```

The, I ran sbatch as follows: `sbatch test_bash`

However, when I view the outputs, it is apparent that only one of the `sruns` in the bash script are being executed... Could anyone tell me where I went wrong and how I can fix it?

**update :  when I look at the error file I get the following : `srun: Job 43969 step creation temporarily disabled, retrying`. I searched the internet and it says that this could be caused by not specifying the memory and hence not having enough memory for the second job.. but I thought that I already specifeid the memory when I did `--mem_per_cpu=300MB`?

**update : I have tried changing the code as said as in here : [Why are my slurm job steps not launching in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191801/why-are-my-slurm-job-steps-not-launching-in-parallel), but.. still it didn't work

**potentially pertinent information: our node has about 96cores, which seems odd when compared to tutorials that say one node has like 4cores or something

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `--exclusive` to the `srun` command line:

```
srun --exclusive --ntasks=1 python FINAL_ARGPARSE_RUN.py --n_division 30 --start_num ${num} &
```

This will instruct `srun` to use a sub-allocation and work as you intended.

Note that the `--exclusive` option has a different meaning in this context than if used with `sbatch`.

Note also that different versions of Slurm have a distinct canonical way of doing this, but using `--exclusive` should work across most versions.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Actually, I already tried what you have said, (as written in the second update to my question), but it still seems to gives me the same results...

Comment: (it also gives the same error, `srun : Job 43972 step creation temporarily disabled, retrying`)

Comment: maybe try `-c1 -n1 -N1 --exclusive` ?

Comment: thank you! unfortunately, it still gives out the same error and only one task seems to be executed

Comment: Since ntask method doesnt seem to work, are there other ways to run parallel? I initially tried submitting multiple jobs(with one task per job), but found out that resulted in the jobs being run serially… or should I try job array? (I havent studied what is it yet, but at first glance it seemed like using job array will enable the code to be run in parallel)

Comment: I solved it! turns out the `pwd ;hostname; date` line of the code caused problems! (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71978596/slurm-job-arrays-dont-work-when-used-in-argparse/71979187#71979187)

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have solved your problem which turned out to be something else, and that you have already specified `--mem_per_cpu=300MB` in your `sbatch` script, I would like to add that in my case, my Slurm setup doesn't allow `--mem_per_cpu` in `sbatch`, only `--mem`. So the `srun` command will still allocate all the memory and block the subsequent steps. The key for me, is to specify `--mem_per_cpu` (or `--mem`) **in the `srun` command.**