# Slurm job arrays don't work when used in argparse

Tags: python, linux, jobs, slurm

I am trying to run multiple things at once (i.e. in a parallel manner) with different values of the variable `--start_num`. I have designed the following bash script,

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name fmriGLM #job name을 다르게 하기 위해서
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH -t 16:00:00 # Time for running job
#SBATCH -o /scratch/connectome/dyhan316/fmri_preprocessing/FINAL_loop_over_all/output_fmri_glm.o%j #%j : job id 가 들어가는 것
#SBATCH -e /scratch/connectome/dyhan316/fmri_preprocessing/FINAL_loop_over_all/error_fmri_glm.e%j
pwd; hostname; date
#SBATCH --ntasks=30
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=3000MB
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=5
#SBATCH -a 0-5

python FINAL_ARGPARSE_RUN.py --n_division 30 --start_num $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
```

Then, I ran `sbatch --exclude master array_bash_2`, but it doesn't work. I have tried searching many sites and have tried multiple things, but still the error `FINAL_ARGPARSE_RUN.py: error: argument --start_num: expected one argument` pops out in the error file, making me feel that the `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` in the bash script hasn't been properly done...?

Could anyone explain why this is and how I can fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. Take the chance to remove the "linux" tag, see its description for why. Also, read [ask], because "it doesn't work" is not an error description. Rather, provide the output you received and your thoughts explaining what you think about it.

Comment: sorry for the insufficient explanation! Fortunately, my question was answered! next time, I will be sure to take what you have said into account when writing a question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your line `pwd; hostname; date`.
Don’t add any non-SBATCH lines in between `#SBATCH` directives as Slurm will stop processing at that point, meaning you are not submitting an array job, but just a single job.
Move that line after the last `#SBATCH` line and it should work now.