# Make sure there's always N jobs running/allocated out of a batch of M with SLURM

Tags: slurm

I need to use [SLURM](https://slurm.schedmd.com/) to perform cluster computing and I would like to reach the following outcome: out of a batch file containing `M` tasks, only `N` are in execution/reserved at any one time.

I have a batch file with `M` tasks, each one consisting of something like this:

```
cd $my_specific_directory
srun [OPTIONS] $(cat my_sim_command)&
cd ..
```

The issue is that the batch file could potentially have hundreds of entries, but I don't want them to be requesting resources for all of them at once, since these resources are shared.

I would like to be able to claim `N`  jobs (however many nodes might be needed for that) at the time, making sure that when one of those `N` ends, the next one in the batch file is started.

Is this the purpose of the `--ntasks` option? Would something like

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=5

cd $dir1
srun [OPTIONS] --ntasks=1 $(cat my_sim_command)&
cd $dir2
srun [OPTIONS] --ntasks=1 $(cat my_sim_command)&
...
cd $dir20
srun [OPTIONS] --ntasks=1 $(cat my_sim_command)&
cd ..
```

work? By "work" I mean, make sure that there's always 5 jobs out of my batch running, until completion of the list in the batch file.

I have opened [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/758348/bash-script-make-sure-there-is-always-n-processes-launched-on-slurm?noredirect=1#comment1445124_758348) on linux.stackexchange where I'm trying to do it "myself", however without too much success so I decided that SLURM itself should have already this functionality, though I don't know it.

Comment: Did you thought about job arrays?

Comment: Hi, I don't know what a job array is, will look it up, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal way is to use [Job Array](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html) with ***`%`***.
`%` ensures that only the specified number of tasks are executed in parallel.

For example,

```
#SBATCH --array=1-100:4%5
```

Here, 100 tasks can be executed using a single job script but `%` ensures that only `5` tasks are executing at the same time.

I think this is the scenario you are looking for. For sample use cases with Job array, visit this [URL](https://rcs.ucalgary.ca/How_to_use_array_jobs_in_SLURM).

A detailed discussion on ntasks can be seen in this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186698/what-does-the-ntasks-or-n-tasks-does-in-slurm). As per my understanding, job array approach is ideal for you. Nevertheless, you could make it work using the proposed approach but it is rather ineffecient. You have to keep track of already executed tasks and allot sufficient time in job script so that all of your tasks are executed. Otherwise, you might need to relaunch job script to run the remaining applications. It is possible but not ideal.